# Machine learning to recognize different dollar bills

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, svm, kinect-sdk

I want to create an application that I can regonize different dollar bills.Well I am using C# visual studio 2010, kinect and emgucv. I did the part to get frame with kinect but I have a question What kind of machine learning do you recommend to recognize bills and why? I dont know if I must work with neuronal network, SVM, haar classifier. I dont know!

Comment: The best way would be for you to read about each of these ML techniques. Not only you'll find the best way to achieve your goal, but you will learn a lot about everything and that will help you take a decision faster in future projects.

Comment: Yes But I read some machine learning in other to take a decision!!What kind of ML will you choose??